# What are MVVM limitations?

Tags: .net, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

**BACKGROUND**

I am learning MVVM, and found that it's great in displaying data / model.

But

I think, it's only good for displaying a simple model not that good to display a complicated model.

**QUESTION**

Is it true that MVVM has certain limitation (a numbered list or link would be great) or am I wrongly construct the model since MVVM is already versatile under any circumstances?

The "limitation" I meant is focused on the limitation on how the model should be made.

The reason I make this post is because I feel a lot of obstacle in constructing my application display in MVVM way.

**ETC**

Is there any other pattern beside MVVM to use in WPF?

Btw, sorry if it's a "not clear what is asked" question.

---

In case it's needed, my "case" is I am making a [numbered musical notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbered_musical_notation) scores writer. Please don't ask "no one use numbered system, why bother?". In my country, it still commonly used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds as though you need to read some more MVVM tutorials to me. MVVM is a development methodology, not a platform. There is no requirement to use MVVM to develop a WPF Application, but doing so often simplifies the whole procedure. MVVM has no relation to the size of a project, except maybe that it suits bigger applications better because of the required basic framework required.

Complicated models can be displayed just as easily as simple models. It's entirely possible to have child view models in parent view models, or just huge view models if that's your preference. MVVM is just a way to implement the *Separation of Concerns* principle and really not as complicated as some make it out to be.

You have a data model, which are business classes that are used in view models, either directly or wrapped in other view models as you prefer, and those view models are bound to views to display the data and provide user input. There's really not much to it than that.