# Get XAML View element without breaking MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I need a reference to a Visual (one element of a XAML View Window) in my ViewModel to work with VisualTreeHelper methods like `VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(Visual reference)` but I do not want to break MVVM rules and just name the viewport3d and provide it as a reference when instancing my ViewModel.

Currently I am binding the geometry as content like this to my ViewModel:

```
<Viewport3D>
     <ModelVisual3D Content="{Binding SceneContent.Content}"/>
</Viewport3D>
```

But I do not see the MVVM possibility to get the containing ModelVisual3D into my ViewModel. Is there a standard (may be data-binding) approach to this in MVVM applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using MVVM, we *don't* 'get view elements'. If you need to do something with a UI element, then that has nothing to do with MVVM. If you need to use the `VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds` method, then once again, that has absolutely nothing to do with MVVM... why do so many people *claim* to use MVVM, but know nothing about it?

Therefore, your question is invalid. It is entirely appropriate in situations like these for you to use the code behind. In fact, this is a perfect example of when we *should* use the code behind when following the MVVM methodology. If it is only UI related, then it has no purpose being in a view model, so simply don't put it there.

Please read the answer to the [What are MVVM limitations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476469/what-are-mvvm-limitations/24480338#24480338) question to get some further insight into MVVM.

Comment: OK, I am aware that MVVM is just a principle for developing code that is maintainable, modular, testable etc. by using only loose coupling between certain software units. But e.g. I need a method to get the bounding box of a scene to make changes to my camera control (ViewModel). The View is just a XAML definition of a UI made by a XAML designer/professional and so I do not want to put some further logic there. How would you organize this scenario? Should the camera control (it is an only-UI-related-unit I think) be either part of the view?

Comment: In my opinion, all data for UI-only controls should exist entirely in the view.

Comment: Considering your answer, I finally came to the approach NOT implementing it within my view: I need bounding box of the scene and some picking functionality from the VisualTreeHelper. But the scene (geometry) is part of my Model. So why not directly implement these features (without VisualTreeHelper) within my ViewModel, where I have access to my Model. Using the VisualTreeHelper is fancy but it works on an representation of the data (XAML Tree) that has actually been generated from my Model. Nontheless Your answer was inspiring for reconsidering my setup.

Comment: Actually I reconsidered the whole setup again, and implemented the features within my View now. I can use functionality of VisualTreeHelper and realized features belong to the view. I took the way of implementing a CustomControl encapsulating the functionality.